# pie chart error: Error in seq.int(x[i], x[i + 1], length.out = n) : 'length.out' must be a non-negative number

Tags: r, pie-chart

I'm new to R and I'm playing around with making a pie chart out of counts of names using R 3.2.2.  I've aggregated by data into the dataframe data.agg2, which is displayed below:

```
> data.agg2
                          Group.1          x
1                             Sam  210341519
2                            Mike 1619119095
3                           Carol    5863766
4                           Chuck   42306834
5                           Brent   34369163
6                           Linda   22083392
7                          Ashley  314110358
```

However, when I run the data to make the pie chart using the following command:

```
pie(data.agg2$x, labels=data.agg2$Group.1, main = "Popularity of Names")
```

I subsequently get this combination of errors/warnings:

```
Error in seq.int(x[i], x[i + 1], length.out = n) : 
  'length.out' must be a non-negative number
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In pie(data.agg2$x, labels = data.agg2$Group.1, main = "Popularity of Names") :integer overflow in 'cumsum'; use 'cumsum(as.numeric(.))'
2: In sum(x) : integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))
```

I don't understand why the length.out at the end of the sequence command would be a negative number, given the large numbers in my x column. I've tried changing my x column, originally an integer, to numeric using `as.numeric(as.factor(data.agg2$x))`, and that didn't seem to do the trick (though perhaps I did it wrong?).  Also, I've mostly focused on exploring the error itself, but perhaps it's tied to the warnings I'm getting--my research into how to solve these warnings point back to switching the x variable into numeric form, which (if I did it right above), doesn't solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The numbers are too large. Try `pie(data.agg2$x/10000, labels=data.agg2$Group.1, main = "Popularity of Names")`.

Comment: That did the trick--thanks, @RHertel.

Comment: Maybe you've already solved this problem... I had a similar problem due to "Inf" values, so it'd be interesting also check it!